# Operating system- processes

Tags: operating-system

Are any of these true? Why?

In UNIX/Linux system, a child process continues to execute the same program as its parent process.
Context switch is more expensive than mode switch.

A process can access the data on a hard disk directly without the involvement of the kernel.

Any two processes can communicate using an ordinary (unnamed) pipe

Answer (score -1):

> In UNIX/Linux system, a child process continues to execute the same program as its parent process.

Mostly true because of the way `fork()` works (often the child calls `exec()` a little later, but that only happens later). It's not necessarily always true though (e.g. you can start a process by using `posix_spawn()` instead, or plain old `system()` in C).

> Context switch is more expensive than mode switch.

Too little information to determine whether this is true or not. E.g. "context switch" can mean switching from user-space to kernel space, or from "kernel context" to "IRQ context", or... In the same way a "mode switch" could be anything (video mode switch? Privilege level change?). I can only say that some things that are called context switches are more expensive than some things that are called mode switches, and some are less expensive.

> A process can access the data on a hard disk directly without the involvement of the kernel.

Mostly false. The only case where it might be potentially possible is if you stretch the definition of "hard drive" to include NVRAM as persistent storage; but even in that case I'm not sure if Linux supports the direct mapping of NVRAM into user-space (yet).

> Any two processes can communicate using an ordinary (unnamed) pipe

No. If you randomly select any 2 processes and expect them to communicate via. a pipe then it's extremely likely that it won't make any sense to anyone (e.g. imagine sending digitized sound from one process to a CRON daemon that's not expecting it). The processes would have to be designed to coordinate the creation of the pipe's endpoints and agree on their roles (which is sender, which is receiver), and agree on the protocol used for the data transferred over the pipe (just sending/receiving raw bytes is not communication, in the same way that hearing is not the same as listening/understanding).

Answer (score -1):

Context of a process is represented in PCB.

There are two possibilities after calling fork():

- parent and children execute concurrently
- parent waits untill child terminate.

The parent can wait for the child to terminate by calling wait() system call OR the parent can continue to execute

->The child often starts a new and different program within itself via exec() system call.

Modularity:

program-> process-> thread

so thread switching is easy than context switching because threads of same process have same address space.

Processes can access a critical section of code i.e shared resources through "mutex" and "semaphores".

The processes can communicate with each other through "inter-process comm".
1. shared data
2. message passing